What happens "Actually" after waves collide?
I'm high school student so i don't know well and this would be short or easy question for some people but it still suffer for me to imagine what actually happens after wave function collide.
I have learned conventionally waves would merely pass through when waves meet each other.
I think it would be right if waves are perfectly same.
But just by my imagination, if there are any different properties of the waves, there should be any changes after collide even the changes are negligible and really tiny.
maybe there are some elastic collisions?
i don't know, i hope to know there are any changes "really" after collide.

There is such thing as elastic/inelastic scattering and side effects thereof if I'm not mistaken, though I'm not well-studied enough on the subject to answer fully.

I think wavefunction is not exactly a physical real wave, more like a Dr. Strange's all possible worlds set of outcomes... In the film "Endgame", Dr. Strange was in effect calculating that the outcome of the Avenger's wavefunction colliding with Thanos's wavefunction will be the destruction of the Avenger's own wavefunction, except for the 1 specific thread which survives the collision. What is collided is the set of possible outcomes...

... it seems also why colliding 2 originally separate wavefunction always results in a double-dimensional combined wavefunction (e.g. the 3D spatial wavefunction of the Avenger colliding with the 3D spatial wavefunction of Thanos cannot conceptually be described by a resultant combined 3D wavefunction like normal physical waves, but requires a mind-blowing 6D two-body wavefunction to describe the outcomes).

Ordinary waves (like those in water or air) pass through each other (they temporarily add up together) and then emerge unchanged, as long as their amplitude is not extreme. Downstream from their intersection point,  a pattern of peaks and valleys will appear where their summation turns out (+) or (-).
For quantum particles, the story is very different. depending on their type, quantum particles can either pass straight through another without changing or scatter off one another like colliding billiard balls.

When waves collide, they interact with each other through a process known as interference. There are two main types of interference:

Constructive Interference: This occurs when the peaks (high points) and troughs (low points) of the waves align with each other. As a result, the waves combine to form a larger amplitude wave. In other words, their effects add together, creating a stronger wave.

Destructive Interference: This happens when the peak of one wave aligns with the trough of another wave. The effects of the waves cancel each other out to some extent, resulting in a smaller amplitude or potentially no wave at all in that region.


These interactions are governed by the principle of superposition, which states that the resultant wave at any point is the sum of the displacements of the individual waves. This principle applies to all types of waves, including sound, light, and water waves.

"Interference" is not waves interacting with each other. It's what we call the static spatial patterns that appear in the wave function when waves from two or more coherent sources pass through each other without interacting. If you follow the waves from any one source through the "interference" region, and if there's nothing in the region to absorb energy from the waves (e.g., no "detector screen") then the waves emerge from the other side of the region completely unchanged.
